# Vista Backup failed: "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect (0x8007007B)"

Tags: backup, hard-drive, windows-vista, corruption

My computer recently attempted to run a backup and failed with the above error code.  I tried creating a new backup on removable media, again this failed.  I watched where the backup failed and found some files that were behaving oddly, including one that was nameless, without file type, size or properties.  The more I deleted, the more I found.

I ran an update install of vista to repair my system files to no avail.  Saved all my files to removable media and did a clean install, and still no joy.  Oddly, my PHP folder survived the clean install.  Deleted it, no luck.

I have run memory and hard disk diagnostics and everything looks fine.  Most perplexing.  Any help would be appreciated.  I have started a thread on the Microsoft Answers forum and started a dialogue with Dell, my comp manufacturer, about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the fix, which cost me £75 from Dell Tech Support, was to clean install Vista again, this time removing all partitions.  I couldn't believe it when it worked - the recovery partition was nothing to do with the problem, but it worked.  Grr.  Oh well, you learn something new every day, and now I know for future.

Answer (score 0):

Use a partitioning tool (Disk Management might tell you) to determine if your main partition is set to Active. There is a [known issue](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-security/116865-windows-complete-pc-backup-error-0x8007007b.html) where third-party boot managers kill the Complete PC Backup. I'm guessing PC manufacturers may have a recovery or diagnostics partition set as the active, booting partition.

Comment: Hm, I will investigate that, but my backup used to work fine, and I haven't made any changes to the partition.  I did run ubuntu from disk, just once, and it promised to make no changes to my system, but coincidentally it is since doing that that I have problems.